# OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm overriding OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) in an Adorner class in C#

In this Method I'm trying to draw images stored in my imageCache Dictionary.
The problem is OnRender Method gets called before the Thread that stores my images in the dictionary finishes.

I tried to Thread.Sleep(60) this works but my program got really slow.

Can you guys give me ideas how I can overpass this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does you thread which stores images in a dictionary run once? If so, I suggest you to do nothing in your `OnRender` until your image-storing thread finishes.

But if your image-storing thread runs for every render or frequently, you might need to implement some [thread syncronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsw9f9ts%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (well you'll need it for the fist case too). For example, you can have reference to a dictionary with old images for rendering purposes, then after your worker thread built a new dictionary, you can use `lock` and assign a new dictionary to that reference.

(That's all I can suggest with so little input)

Comment: Thank you, my dictionary can be empty at the beginning and it runs frequently to update itself.

Comment: @raym0nd, so I guess you need to check if it's empty in your `OnRender` and do your rendering only if it is not empty. Also, if you want to use in render your previous dictionary while you're building a new one, update the reference the render routine uses only after it's built. And do not forget about thread syncronization.

Comment: @raym0nd, In my opinion it's not a great idea to lock UI thread for prolonged durations, but the decision is yours.

Comment: I need to wait for my other thread to finish so I can get the correct input from my dictionary, my waiting time isnt that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock and synchronize the threads by using Mutex.

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();
```

and then you can lock and release the methods you want by using

```
mut.WaitOne();
mut.ReleaseMutex();
```

and here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) tutorial.